Local index buffer from a group of merged meshlets
I'm developing a Hierarchical LOD Nanite-style system using meshoptimizer. I'm having troubles with how to create a local index buffer from a group of merged meshlets. Is there a correct way to create a local index buffer from a group of merged meshlets? Do you have any suggestions or advice on that?
Many thanks
